# Can a dynamic class be styled using CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a class called `.box-159` where the number changes every time the screen is refreshed. Is there a way to define this field (say `background-color`) in the CSS?

Comment: Does CSS allow wildcards? I don't think so. You could refer to the element by something other than the class

Comment: are you asking to style the element differently based on the number at the end of the class?

Answer (score 35):

Yes it is possible just by using CSS only.

### Option #1 - Match by prefix value

- Use  [**CSS Class selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors)  `^="class"` which select all elements whose class is prefixed by "**box-**"

```css
[class^="box-"] {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  display:block
}
```

```html
<div class="box-159"></div>
<span class="box-147"></span>
<article class="box-76878"></article>
```

### Option #2 - Match by contains at least one value

- Use another **CSS class selector** `*="class"` (equivalent to [CSS attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)) which select all elements whose  class contains at least one substring "**box-**".

```css
[class*="box-"] {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  display:block
}
```

```html
<div class="box-159"></div>
<span class="box-147"></span>
<article class="box-76878"></article>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can add an additional class, like so, then both those elements will have the class' CSS attributes:

```css
.box-class {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-class box-4"></div>
<div class="box-class box-159"></div>
```

Comment: Another class is not necessary, this can be done with a CSS selector alone.

Comment: I just noticed, well it is a non-efficiant, working solution at least :)

Comment: I prefer this solution. Attribute selectors, especially using partial string matching, will always be slower than a simple class selector like this.